# Sentence structure and choices

Tags: grammar

Let's say you're asked to name your top 3 songs by an artist and you can't choose would you say:
1. I can't only/just pick/choose 3
2. I can't pick/choose only/just 3

What sounds better in your opinion? Or maybe you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't pick only 3 songs.

or

> I can't choose just 3 songs.

or

> It's difficult to pick just 3 songs.